# Querying Live Agent Activity

Tags: trigger, soql, liveagent

Is there any way to use SOQL to query Live Agent activity, such as current chat sessions, and the number of people waiting for a chat session to begin?

The only Live Agent related object I see is LiveAgentTranscript, but that doesn't seem to be what we need.

I was looking at the Case object, which has a lot of fields that look useful, but I'm told that is not related to Live Agent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such data in Live Agent is real time and it does not create any records in Salesforce for us to query using SOQL.

Also LiveAgentTranscript only gets created after the chat ends if we exclusively use Salesforce Live Agent routing. Hence we dont get real time data from it.

The best way to visualize the present chat sessions and related data is through the **Live Agent Supervisor tab**. It shows how many chats are in progress, Queue Length for different buttons and key metrics regarding chat activity.
Below is the link

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=live_agent_supervisor_panel.htm&type=0

Answer (score 0):

Now with embedded services, you have LCT's created when chat enters the system and it has the status In Progress when a chat is In Progress vs Completed.